# query to get the SUM

Tags: sql, postgresql

Supposed I have a data of

**code_table**

```
code_id | code_no | stats |
2         60         22A3
3         60         22A3
```

**value_table**

```
value_no | amount_value_one | amount_value_two | amount_diff | code_no |  sample_no  | code_id
1          1200.00             400.00             800.00        60         90          2
1           600.00             200.00             400.00        60        100          3
1          1800.00             600.00            1200.00        60        110          2
2          1200.00            1200.00               0.00        60        110          2
2           800.00             600.00             200.00        60         90          2
2           400.00               0.00             400.00        60        100          3
```

What I want to happen is to get all the **SUM of** `amount_value_two` and just retain the **first** `amount_value_one` which has the `value_no = 1`

the output can be conclude as

```
amount_value_one | SUM_of_amount_value_two | amount_diff | sample_no
1200.00             1000.00                     200.00         90
 600.00              200.00                     400.00         100 
1800.00            1.800.00                       0.00         110
```

so far i have this following query

```
SELECT SUM(p.amount_value_one) as value_one,
SUM(p.amount_value_two) as value_two,
SUM(p.amount_diff) as amount_diff,
p.sample_no as sampleNo FROM value_table p
INNER JOIN code_table On code_table.code_no = p.code_no
WHERE code_table.code_id = p.code_id
AND code_table.stats = '22A3'
GROUP BY p.sample_no
```

the query above that I used is wrong because it gets the sum of both **p.amount_value_one** 
and **p.amount_diff**

its just a test query because i cant imagine what would the query will look like.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the "first" value, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a column that specifies the ordering, then you can use that to figure out the "first" row.  Then use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN p.amount_value_one END) as value_one,
       SUM(p.amount_value_two) as value_two,
       SUM(p.amount_diff) as amount_diff,
       p.sample_no as sampleNo
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.sample_no ORDER BY <ordering column>) as seqnum
      FROM value_table p
     ) p JOIN
     code_table  ct
     ON ct.code_no = p.code_no AND
        ct.code_id = p.code_id
WHERE ct.stats = '22A3'
GROUP BY p.sample_no
```